# its taking the screenshot but not showing in gallery

Tags: java, android, bitmap

It's taking the screenshot but not showing in gallery when I check the device storage there are screenshot files but when I try to click them it says unable to find app to open this file.

I have to share the ui of my application as an image

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Bitmap bitmap = getScreenShot(rootView);
        store(bitmap,"share_image");
    }
});


public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}


public  void store(Bitmap bm, String fileName){
   dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Screenshots";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dirPath, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        shareImage(file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void shareImage(File file){
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Screenshot"));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your file *share_image*. It has no extension, so the system will treat it as a blank, basic file.

As you are using *png* compression, add ".png" to the file name.

```
store(bitmap,"share_image.png");
```

Comment: but i had make an extension .png on  store() function

Comment: This will tell the library how to format the data in your file so it can be read as a PNG. But when the system browses the files, it does not know how the data is formatted inside your file. It sees a file called "share_image" and is like "meh, a blank file, totally not a PNG image, let's move on..."